# Want to clean Group Policy from my machine (Vista 64) before I update to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, group-policy

On my way home from a visit to Virginia, I purchased a machine from Best Buy (a couple years ago).  I didn't want them to put all the sales crap on the machine and it was the only one Dell left with a 5.9 user rating.

They packed it up and I took it home.  Turned out to have the Best Buy GPO settings still on it.  After fighting with them about getting full access to my new machine (the store's 3 hours from here)

I managed to get most of the admin rights turned on myself (using info on-line).  Now I want to update my machine to 7, but I want to once and for all get rid of the gp's on this machine.  I found a way (on-line) to disable the group policy (startup = 4 in the registry if anyone's seen this before), but I believe some permissions are left over from that old Best Buy domain.

How can I get rid of the rest of the group policy left on my machine before I upgrade to 7?  Sorry, but I've spent 3 days trying to figure this out.  I don't want to reinstall all of my software from doing a clean install.

Comment: In three days you could have backed up, installed 7 clean and reinstalled all yours software, which would be your best choice. :)  Have you disjoined the machine from their domain?